# No route found for "GET /home"

Tags: symfony

I am using Symfony 3.4.3. 
This is my routing in 
`app/config/routing.yml`:

```
blog:
    resource: "@BlogBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
```

this is my controller from `BlogBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php`

```
<?php

namespace BlogBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @Route("/home", name="home_route")
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('BlogBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

And when I go to http://localhost:8000/home address I am getting this error: `No route found for "GET /home"`

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Same error with http://localhost:8000/web/app_dev.php/home ?

Comment: Yes I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You add to set the route annotation **on the action**

```
<?php

namespace BlogBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/home", name="home_route")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('BlogBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

If you use annotation on the class, **is to prefix all actions**